# What are common causes of ext4 file system corruption?

Tags: ext4, fsck

I'm dealing with regular corruption of an ext4 non-root filesystem holding a data cache. The cache is specifically of images cut into pieces for easier processing later.

The error in the application logs:

```
OSError: [Errno 74] Bad message: '/redacted/path/to/sliced/image/data'
```

The error in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
kernel: [163197.788364] EXT4-fs error (device md127): ext4_lookup:1590: inode #125532502: comm python3.6: iget: checksum invalid
```

The filesystem is on a RAID5 array with three SSDs.

Running `fsck` afterwards always fixes the issue, at least the 4-5 times it has happened so far. However, restarting the running process is obviously a headache and it doesn't seem wise to swallow this exception (`OSError`) and mask many other issues.

I'm able to trace back to exactly when the file was written (perhaps hours before the exception occurs), but `/var/log/syslog` reports no issues at that point either.

What are common causes of ext4 file system corruption? For example, what programming mistakes typically lead to corruption only at scale and specifically in python (e.g. improper use of locks)? Do errors in the kernel or hardware often lead to corruption without an error in the system logs?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error, **assuming all the errors are inode checksum failures**, means that the ext4fs module *thinks* the metadata has gotten corrupted. Of course, if you also see different errors, then this is clearly not the answer.

Inode checksum errors are caused by some low-level tool or module (not Python, for a certainty!) disagreeing with the ext4fs layer about what the inode structure should be. Not updating a single bit would then result in a checksum error.

The whole inode thing happens at the interface between the kernel, the filesystem driver and the low-level filesystem functions - that was described to me as the IOSS, the I/O SubSystem.

This kind of error can also be a IOSS/FS bug (there was [one such occurrence some years ago](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-ext4/msg55802.html), when xattr conflicted with checksumming). So, if possible, you might want to try with an updated kernel/filesystem driver.

Comment: What does `IOSS` stand for?

Comment: @davidvandebunte sorry. That's Input Output SubSystem. Correcting answer

Answer (score 1):

See [hard drive - Are these SATA errors dangerous? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous/1171384#1171384). I'd previously found `FPDMA QUEUED` errors in `/var/log/syslog` but removed a fourth SSD in the RAID array that was the only source of these error messages. So although this is apparently a common cause of ext4 file system corruption, it is no longer an explanation for these errors.